# Download xml page asynccronosly and write on a file in Java?

Tags: java, file, asynchronous, io, download

I have to donwload data based on a list of id (5 millions ids).

I want to download a page from all this id and then write it on a file. There is a way to download them and write on a file in async mode? I have do this syncronosly but take to mutch time.

This is my code synchronous:

```
 while ((sCurrentId = inputFile.readLine()) != null) {
     counterLine++;
     WikiLine wikiLine=download(sCurrentId,counterLine);
     if(wikiLine!=null)
          outputFile.append(wikiLine.toString());
 }
```

Help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could have a thread reading all lines and adding them in a queue, another thread could then read all lines from the queue and write it to a file, perhaps something like this:

```
final SynchronousQueue<String> wikiLines = new SynchronousQueue<>();

Thread fetchXmlThread = new Thread(() -> {
    while ((sCurrentId = inputFile.readLine()) != null) {
        counterLine++;
        WikiLine wikiLine = download(sCurrentId,counterLine);
        if (wikiLine != null)
             wikiLines.put(wikiLine.toString());
    }
});

Thread writeToFileThread = new Thread(() -> {
    for(;;) {
        outputFile.append(wikiLines.take());
    }
});

fetchXmlThread.start();
writeToFileThread.start();
```

Do note that the writeToFileThread will continue blocking even after the fetchXmlThread is closed, so you should implement something in order to stop that thread. This could be done by interrupting the thread while it is blocking (due to `wikiLines.take()`) or changing `for(;;)` by something that can check whether there are any lines left and whether the other thread is still running.

If you do require more than 2 threads you might want to look into [executors](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/executors.html).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, I resolved this with executors. But also your solution souds great! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use an **Excutor** to launch multiple tasks in meantime and treat all with separated Thread.
You define a **Callable** class to read input file and then submit the task for your ID with the `submit(Callable)` method of the **Executor**. Have a look to [ExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#submit(java.util.concurrent.Callable)).